# Adding/replacing object in a deeply nested Redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am having a problem update an object of the state tree (create missing keys if they do not exist). I am using the spread operator! Here is my action:

```
 export function addResourceOption(value) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(addRsrcOpt(value))
  }
};
```

I am taking just "value" from the action and I am using the current state values (selectedResource,resourceSubName,selectedResourceOption). here is how I am accessing the state tree:

```
state: {
   physical_machines:{
       state.selectedResource:{
              state.enteredSubResourceName:{ "name": state.selectedResourceOption, "value": action.payload.value}
```

So I am getting the error: cannot read "enteredSubResourceName" of undefined. Here is my reducer code:

```
 case ADD_RESOURCE_OPTION:
        return {
            ...state,
            //resourcesOptionsTable: [...state.resourcesOptionsTable, { name: action.payload.name, value: action.payload.value }],
            physical_machines:{
                ...state.physical_machines,

                [state.selectedResource]:{
                    ...state.physical_machines.selectedResource,
                    [state.enteredSubResourceName]:{
                        //...state.physical_machines.selectedResource[state.enteredSubResourceName],
                        [state.selectedResourceOption] : action.payload.value
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

I edited my code, I can reach and place a new object in the right location, but it is overriding the previous one!

Comment: Can you avoid the nesting? If so, it will probably make things easier, and save you some hassle in the code that consumes the data in your store.

Comment: Unfortunately,  I can't update my state tree now. I need to go through the hassle of updating nested store :(

Comment: The error you mention would suggest that `state` itself was undefined, but we can't see how it is set here. Can you show us a more complete example of the reducer, e.g. the function signature and a switch with a single case?

Comment: In fact the error  I was getting is caused by this line: ...state.physical_machines.selectedResource[state.enteredSubResourceName]. I removed it and I can place a new object successfully BUT it is  overriding the previous one!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very certain but can you look and test this :

```
 case ADD_RESOURCE_OPTION:
    return {
        ...state,
        physical_machines:{
            ...state.physical_machines,

            state.selectedResource:{
                ...state.physical_machines.selectedResource,
                state.enteredSubResourceName:{
                    ...state.physical_machines.selectedResource.enteredSubResourceName,
                    selectedResourceOption : action.payload.value
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I managed to solve the problem using this reducer code:

```
        let { selectedResource,  enteredSubResourceName, selectedResourceOption } = state
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            physical_machines: {
               ...state.physical_machines,
               [selectedResource + "." + enteredSubResourceName]:{
                ...state.physical_machines[selectedResource + "." + enteredSubResourceName],
                    [state.selectedResourceOption.name] : action.payload.value
               }
            }
          });
```

I did some modification to the requirement as I joined the (selectedResource + "." + enteredSubResourceName), but it is still valid in my case. Now, I can add values without them overriding eachother. Thank you all for your responses.